# How do I get the redirected url?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I´ve got the following Url:

```
http://sowacs.appspot.com/AWS/webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAICNDB2XMNUH7OIDA&AssociateTag=sometag&BrowseNode=10777&Operation=ItemSearch&SearchIndex=Books&Condition=All&ResponseGroup=ItemIds&ItemPage=1
```

as you click the link you get to a xml file. When you have a look at the Url there´s a timestamp- and a signature-parameter added. I´d like to get this extended Url in a php script. I´m searching for hours and found things like:

```
    function get_web_page( $url ) 
{ 
    $options = array( 
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page 
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,    // return headers 
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects 
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings 
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i 
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect 
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect 
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response 
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects 
    ); 

    $ch      = curl_init( $url ); 
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options ); 
    $content = curl_exec( $ch ); 
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch ); 
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch ); 
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch ); 
    curl_close( $ch ); 

    //$header['errno']   = $err; 
   // $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg; 
    //$header['content'] = $content; 
    print($header[0]); 
    return $header; 
}  
$thisurl = "http://sowacs.appspot.com/AWS/
webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?
Service=AWSECommerceService&
AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAICNDB2XMNUH7OIDA&AssociateTag=sometag&BrowseNode=10777
&Operation=ItemSearch&SearchIndex=Books&Condition=All&ResponseGroup=ItemIds&ItemPage=1
";
$myUrlInfo = get_web_page( $thisurl ); 
echo $myUrlInfo["url"];
```

but this only echos me the first url. Not the extended one. I need this redirection for a amazon-api request. This site generates the signature and the timestamp for me (https://sowacs.appspot.com/) in order for me to perform the api-request. Maybe it´s not a "normal" redirection. I have no idea, I´m relatively new to coding...so my php-script needs the url! Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `$header` array you've got the `return_url` key which contains the Amazon AWS API URL with the timestamp and signature added to the request body.

An example of implementation:

```
function get_web_page( $url ) 
{ 
    $options = array( 
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page 
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,    // return headers 
    ); 

    $ch      = curl_init( $url ); 
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options ); 
    $content = curl_exec( $ch ); 
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch ); 
    curl_close( $ch );

    return $header['redirect_url']; 
} 

$thisurl = "http://sowacs.appspot.com/AWS/webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAICNDB2XMNUH7OIDA&AssociateTag=sometag&BrowseNode=10777&Operation=ItemSearch&SearchIndex=Books&Condition=All&ResponseGroup=ItemIds&ItemPage=1";


// Get Amazon AWS URL
$url = get_web_page($thisurl);

echo $url;
```

The output is the same structure as your example at the top of your post, including timestamp and signature:

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAICNDB2XMNUH7OIDA&AssociateTag=sometag&BrowseNode=10777&Condition=All&ItemPage=1&Operation=ItemSearch&ResponseGroup=ItemIds&SearchIndex=Books&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2014-09-01T03%3A18%3A02.000Z&Signature=IxRHgn7AV2YFq05I6Q33eF3aJuzEqsM5e7e1lW1xG8E%3D
```

Up to you what you want to do with that URL from here, but for example you can either get the contents of the XML document with PHP:

```
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
```

... then use a DOM parser to deal with it, e.g.:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);

$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName('Item');
foreach($items as $item) {
    echo '<li>ASIN: ' . $item->nodeValue . '</li>', PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
<li>ASIN: 1454824573</li>
<li>ASIN: 0615361161</li>
<li>ASIN: 1454807105</li>
<li>ASIN: 1285185242</li>
<li>ASIN: 0314279822</li>
<li>ASIN: 1599417049</li>
<li>ASIN: 0735598223</li>
<li>ASIN: 1454851368</li>
<li>ASIN: 1133191355</li>
<li>ASIN: 1454815485</li>
```

... or redirect the user to it:

```
header("Location: " . $url);
exit;
```

---

Since you mention you are new to coding, I'll explain a little bit about [how Amazon's API works](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html):

1. You need to specify your public key (AWSAccessKeyId)
2. You need to provide a unix timestamp of when the request was made (Amazon uses this to determine whether your request is still valid, as it will ignore a request from last week for example).
3. You need to create a signature, which is a hash of the entire request body including the timestamp and your public key. Normally you'd use a secret key of some sort to sign the request. Essentially this signature is a hashed representation (signature) of the data you're sending in your request. Amazon takes the data you send (excluding the signature), gets your private key and assembles their own signature of what it should be, and compares it to the signature you've provided. If they match, your request is OK!